# Saving a max value of counter to file in JMeter

Tags: testing, soap, wsdl, jmeter

I'm using a SOAP/XML-RPC Request to test a WSDL. Additionally I created a Counter element for this request. Each call of one of the functions has to contain other value in one of parameters.
Is there any possibility to save the maximum counter value to the file?
So when I start test, the value will be loaded from the file and increase by the counter.
At the end, this max value will be again saved to this file. And so on, so on...

Comment: It's not hard to save the value, it's harder to save the right value. So what's the maximum value if you have, say, 10 threads and 10 iterations? is it a value of the last execution (no matter which thread), or always 10th thread and 10th execution? or something else? Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's drop the built-in **Counter** and pass around the thread safe **AtomicInteger**.
Add a **setUp Thread Group** with a **JSR223 Sampler** (choose groovy as a scripting language) to your test plan. We will use it to read the value from the file. This thread group will be executed before all other thread groups and will provide us with the initial value.
Add the following code to the sampler:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

counter = new File($/C:\Path\ToFile\fileName.txt/$).text
ai = new AtomicInteger(Integer.valueOf(counter))
props.put("sharedAtomicInteger", ai)
```

Then add another **JSR223 Sampler** after **SOAP/XML-RPC Request** in your regular **Thread Group**.

Add the following code to the sampler:

```
ai = props.get("sharedAtomicInteger")
variable = ai.incrementAndGet()
vars.put("variable", Integer.toString(variable))
```

Now the value of the improvised counter is stored in a **variable** and can be used in other requests issued by this thread.

Add a **tearDown Thread Group** with a **JSR223 Sampler** to your test plan. This thread group will be executed after all other thread groups and will write the maximum value to the file.

Add the following code to the sampler:

```
ai = props.get("sharedAtomicInteger")
new File($/C:\Path\ToFile\fileName.txt/$).write(ai.toString())
```

Finally, your test plan should look like this:

> setUp Thread Group
>
> > JSR223 Sampler
>
> Regular Thread Group
>
> > SOAP/XML-RPC Request
> >
> > JSR223 Sampler
>
> tearDown Thread Group
>
> > JSR223 Sampler

P.S.
Bear in mind that for brevity's sake I used the put() method of java.util.Properties class which is discouraged in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: Ya, great! I used your tips and I did it in a little simpler way. I described it in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

1. To save value into a file (assumes a [JSR223 Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language)

   ```
   new File("value.txt").text = vars.get("foo")
   ```
2. To read the value from file (assumes [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function)

   ```
   ${__FileToString(value.txt,,)}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I used tips from the first comment and do it in the following way:

[image]

> transfer - Simple Controller
>
> > reading transactionId - **JSR223 PreProcessor**
> >     transfer - **SOAPXML-RPC Request**
> >     saving transactionId - **JSR223 PostProcessor**

#### JSR223 PreProcessor

Script language: groovy

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

initial =  new File("${absolute_path}transactionid.txt").text;
initial = initial.trim();
ai = new AtomicInteger(Integer.valueOf(initial));
transactionId = ai.incrementAndGet();
vars.put("transactionId", Integer.toString(transactionId));
```

#### SOAPXML-RPC Request

Here I'm using `transactionId` as one of the parameters in the SOAP Request.

#### JSR223 PostProcessor

Script language: groovy

```
transactionId = vars.get("transactionId");
new File("${absolute_path}transactionid.txt").write(transactionId.toString());
```

`${absolute_path}` is a variable defined in test plan as:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}
```

It is a path to folder with this JMeter project. This folder also contains file which is read to this test case.